# Django prefetch_related get all manytomany objects

Tags: django, django-models

I'm struggling with this thing:

I need to get all manytomany objects and was thinking of using prefetch_related

this is sample of my models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    companyjobs = models.ManyToManyField(CompanyJob, related_name='jobs')

class CompanyJob(models.Model):
    source = models.CharField(_('Source'), max_length=64, db_index=True)
```

This is what I tried:

```
        search_results = Company.objects.prefetch_related('companyjobs')
```

Now I want to access companyjobs objects.
How do I do it?

Answer (score -1):

You can access companyjobs directly from any instance of the Company model class without the need of `prefetch_related`.

eg.

```
# .all() will get all elements and [0] will get the first
company = Company.objects.all()[0]  

company.companyjobs
# this is actually a ManyToMany Manager
# you deal with it like any other manager so

for companyjob in company.companyjobs.all():
    # all() will again get all items in company.companyjobs
    # here you iterate over all companyjobs in that company
    ... # do what you must
```

Now, we only got one company and go all companyjobs from that.

The way we did that django will make 2 queries to the database.

One for the company and one for the jobs

`prefetch_related` will 'merge' those queries into one
so we get all related jobs while fetching companies from the db

It is quite handy because, if you don't use`prefetch_related`, the more companies you have to deal with you make one extra query to get the jobs for that company which drops performance dramatically.

more info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Comment: `result.companyjobs.all()`?